# Incron, отслеживание удаления файлов

Tags: linux, cron

Есть папка, при загрузке в нее файлов отрабатывается скрипт с помощью incron с модификатором IN_MODIFY.

Какой модификатор/ключ установить, чтобы скрипт выполнялся, если из папки один из файлов удалили?

Пользователь загружает и удаляет из папки файлы со своей виндовой машины. Папка расшарена с помощью samba.

Пробовал модификатор — IN_DELETE скрипт не запускается. 
Имена файлов заранее не известны, имя папки статично.

Пример настройки, которая работает при копировании файлов в папку (вывод incrontab -l):

```
/home/path IN_MODIFY /home/pathwhitscript/script.sh
```

Пример, который, как я подразумеваю, должен запускать мой скрипт при удалении файла из папки:

```
/home/path IN_DELETE /home/pathwhitscript/script.sh
```

Сам скрипт рабочий. Вопрос только в том, как заставить incron запускать скрипт при удалении файла.

Comment: *скрипт не запускается* — вы, вроде бы, не первый день пользуетесь ru.so, и должны бы понимать, что приведённое выражение требует расшифорвки в виде [mcve]

Comment: Пример скрипта не думаю, что требуется он не относится к вопросу. Вопрос в том как запустить его через incron при удалении файла из папки.

Comment: содержание **вашего** скрипта абсолютно неважно. а вот в «минимальном самодостаточном и воспроизводимом примере» должно быть что-то типа `echo тест >> /tmp/file`. и информация о том, появилось ли что-то в файле, и если нет, то какие ошибки были выданы программой *incron*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

подозреваю, что вы поместили в *incrontab* обе эти строки:

```
/home/path IN_MODIFY /home/pathwhitscript/script.sh
/home/path IN_DELETE /home/pathwhitscript/script.sh
```

и получаете в логе после сохранения файла сообщение вида:

> incrond: cannot create watch for user пользователь: (2) No such file or directory

как пишут во многих местах, например, [здесь](http://www.linux-magazine.com/index.php/layout/set/print/Issues/2014/158/Monitoring-with-incron/(tagID)/385), так делать нельзя: для каждого отслеживаемого каталога должна быть только одна строка, в которой может быть перечислено через запятую несколько событий. а для определения, какое именно из событий произошло, передавать параметром вашему скрипту переменную `$%`. примерно так:

```
/home/path IN_MODIFY,IN_DELETE /home/pathwhitscript/script.sh $%
```

---

другие спец-переменные, которые можно использовать в файле *incrontab*, перечислены в [`man 5 incrontab`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab).

Comment: Все верно ошибка была в том, что одновременно использовал две строки для каждой папки. Через запятую, заработало.